# How to automatically answer python inputs

Tags: python-3.x

So say I have

```
name = input("Enter Your Name : ")
print(name)
```

how could I in a bat file or another python file automatically enter a name?
without changing the source

Comment: what do u mean by automatically

Comment: so it puts the name in on its own with like a preset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will try simple stdin redirection:

`test.py`:

```
name = input("Enter Your Name : ")
print("") # NewLine in stdin is consumed by function input
print(name)
```

`input.txt`:

```
John Smith
```

Run in terminal:

```
python test.py < input.txt
```